# How to handle (i.e. log) errors in restify

Tags: node.js, restify

In our restify app, when we pass an error to `next`, a generic 500 error is returned, which is all just fine. However, I need to also log the details of the error somewhere so that I know what happened.

Previously, I worked on an express application, and a centralized error-handling middleware gave us the ability to do any arbitrary code when receiving errors, like logging.

What's the "restify way" to centralizing the logging of error details? I do not want to sprinkle logging statements throughout the entire app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Restify server object emits an `'after'` event once all other route handlers are done for a request. You can put your logging code in an `'after'` event handler:

```
var svr = restify.createServer()
  .get('/hello-world', hello_world_hndlr)
  .on('after', function (req, resp, route, err) {
    // logging here
  })
  .listen(SVR_PORT)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to listening to `'after'` is listening to [`'restifyError'`](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/blob/6c8b5d04318a2efcac97bf01a15676a41699eaa0/docs/api/server-events.md#restifyerror):

```
server.on('restifyError', (req, res, err, cb) => {
  req.log.error(err)
  return cb();
});
```